# What does the author mean by "event handler function wants to unbind itself after it fires"

Tags: javascript, function, event-handling, dom-events

I'm currently studying JavaScript by following the book series "you don't know js"

In the [scope & closure](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch3.md) section of the book, when discussing naming function expressions, the author mentioned.

> Without a name, if the function needs to refer to itself, for
>   recursion, etc., the deprecated arguments.callee reference is
>   unfortunately required. Another example of needing to self-reference
>   is when an event handler function wants to unbind itself after it
>   fires.

Because I am relatively inexperienced at JavaScript, I'm not really sure what "event handler function unbinding" is (I know what "event handler function" is) and how it works.

So I was just wondering if someone could explain it; what it actually does? (a code sample would be even better).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Event handlers can take anonymous functions, this works fine.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",function(){
    console.log("Clicked from anonymous func");
});
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

It is possible to remove an event handler too (`removeEventListener`) and it is possible that the programmer wants that to happen after the event has been raised (typically, you might only want an event to occur once). Using the code above that would be difficult as you have no way to refer to the anonymous function acting as the event listener.

Changing for a named function makes this much easier:

```js
function myEventHandler(){
    console.log("Clicked from named func - but it'll only work once");
    // In an event handler "this" refers to the clicked element
    this.removeEventListener('click',myEventHandler)
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click",myEventHandler);
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: I think I got it. What author meant by "event handler function unbinding" is simply -- removing a function from a event after the function was added to the event. Thank you very much for helping out! Really appreciate it!

Comment: In your second sample, should `Clicked from anonymous func` be `Clicked from named func`?

Comment: @halfer yes, probably should have